# Issue with photos length

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am facing 2 issues related to length of my selected photos:

1. When selecting photos, it lets me to select 5 photos without any issue (it fits my length restriction), however it doesn't save the chosen photos, when I go to the next screen. In another scenario, when I am at the same screen where I choose photos and I choose 6 photos, it selects the 6 photo but the warning popup will appear and say that its currently supports 5, then when I go to next screen its saves the selected photos unlike previously.
2. If I deselect photos and then try to select another photos (still in my length limit) popup jumps with selection limit and doesn't let me choose photos, when I go to the next screen it saves the changes from previous selection and not from current one.

---

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    View,
    ScrollView,
    Image,
    Dimensions,
    TextInput,
    Text,
    StatusBar,
    TouchableHighlight,
    Linking,
    Keyboard,
    CameraRoll,
    KeyboardAvoidingView
} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {ActionCreators} from '../redux/actions';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import Colors from '../constants/Colors';
import api from '../api';
import {
    getEmailAddress,
    showError,
    renderMessageBar,
    registerMessageBar,
    unregisterMessageBar
} from '../utils/ComponentUtils';
import {
    regularHeader,
    mainHeader
} from '../utils/Headers';
import {NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation';
import {SelectionLimitDialog} from '../utils/Dialogs';
import {ifIphoneX, isIphoneX} from 'react-native-iphone-x-helper';
import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-navigation';

// specific component imports.
import {List, ListItem} from 'react-native-elements'
import {Button} from 'react-native-elements'
import Loader from '../components/Loader';
import LoaderError from '../components/LoaderError';
import SelectedPhoto from '../components/SelectedPhoto';

class MultiSafeeScreen extends React.Component 
{
    static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
        const {params} = navigation.state;
        const isIncome = params ? params.isIncome : false;
        const notificationAction = params ? params.notificationAction : () => {};
        const isShowBack = params ? params.isShowBack : false;

        return mainHeader({
            isShowBack: isShowBack,
            backAction: () => navigation.goBack(),
            notificationAction: () => notificationAction(),
            income: isIncome
        });
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.selectedPhotos = [];

        this.state = {
            photos: null,
            loader: {
                loading: 0,
                message: "Loading photos..."
            },  
            selectedPhotos: [],
            supportLength: 5
        };

        this.props.navigation.setParams({notificationAction: this.onNotification, isIncome: this.props.isNewNotifications});
    }

    UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        if (newProps.isNewNotifications !== this.props.isNewNotifications) {
            this.props.navigation.setParams({notificationAction: this.onNotification, isIncome: newProps.isNewNotifications});
        }           
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        registerMessageBar(this.refs.alert);

        let options = {
            first: 30,
            assetType: 'Photos',            
        }

        CameraRoll.getPhotos(options)
        .then(r => {
            this.setState({
                photos: r.edges,
                loader: {
                    loading: 1,
                    message: "Loading photos..."
                },                                  
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
             //Error Loading Images
        });

        StatusBar.setHidden(false);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        unregisterMessageBar();

        this.props.setSelectedPhotos(0);
    }

    onNotification = () => {
        this.props.setNewNotifications(false);
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Notifications");
    }

    closeKeyboard = () => {
        Keyboard.dismiss();
    }

    onSelectPhoto = (photo, index) => {
        let photos = new Set([...this.selectedPhotos]);
        let len = photos.size + 1 ;
        console.log('photos')

        if (len > this.state.supportLength) {           
            this.limitDialog.open();
            this.setState({selectedPhotos: this.selectedPhotos});
            this.props.setSelectedPhotos(len);

        }
        else {
            photos.add(photo);
            this.selectedPhotos = Array.from(photos);

        }
    }

    onDeselectPhoto = (photo, index) => {
        let photos = new Set([...this.state.selectedPhotos]);
        let len = photos.size - 1;

        photos.delete(photo);

        this.setState({selectedPhotos: Array.from(photos)});
        this.props.setSelectedPhotos(len);
    }

    onNext = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("MultiSafeeCreate", {
            isShowBack: true,
            selected: [...this.state.selectedPhotos]
        });     
    }

    renderLoader() {
        let {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');
        let photoWidth = width/3;

        if (this.state.loader.loading === 0) {
            return <Loader style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}} message={this.state.loader.message}/>
        }
        else if (this.state.loader.loading === 2) {
            return <LoaderError style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}} message={this.state.loader.message}/>
        }

        // if photos are null do nothing, else if empty show onbording
        // if has photos show photos.
        if (this.state.photos === null) {
            return <Loader style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}} message={this.state.loader.message}/>
        }
        else {
            return (
                <View style={{width: width, maxHeight: 600}}>
                    <ScrollView >
                        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', width: width, flexWrap: 'wrap',marginBottom:40, justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                        {
                            this.state.photos.map((p, i) => {
                                return (
                                    <SelectedPhoto
                                        key={i}
                                        index={i}
                                        style={{
                                            width: photoWidth,
                                            height: photoWidth,

                                        }}
                                        borderColor = "white" 

                                        limit={this.state.supportLength}
                                        photo={p}
                                        onSelectPhoto={this.onSelectPhoto}
                                        onDeselectPhoto={this.onDeselectPhoto}
                                    />
                                );
                            })
                        }
                        </View>
                    </ScrollView>
                    <View style={{ position:'absolute', right:-15, top:475 }}>
                        <Button

                            onPress={this.onNext}  
                            containerViewStyle={{width: width}}
                            backgroundColor={Colors.red}
                            title='NEXT' />
                    </View>             
                </View>
            );
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: Colors.white}}>
                {this.renderLoader()}
                <SelectionLimitDialog ref={(el) => this.limitDialog = el} />
                {renderMessageBar()}
            </View>
        );
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch);
}

function mapStatesToProps(state) {
    return {
        isNewNotifications: state.isNewNotifications
    };
}

export default connect(mapStatesToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MultiSafeeScreen);
```